# Salt visible in Cython generated .c file

Tags: python, cython

To protect (read: make it harder to reverse) I'm using Cython to create a .c file I used this guide:(https://medium.com/@xpl/protecting-python-sources-using-cython-dcd940bb188e)

For fun, I looked into the .c file, and suddenly I saw the salt that I'm using for my license check.... not good.

From the .c file:

```
  /* "delay.py":916
 * log("serial: " + ser)
 * 
 * enc = ser+"SecretSalt"             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 * h = hashlib.md5(enc.encode())
 * lic = getIni('license','')
 */
```

Any ideas on how to improve this?

Br

Anders

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to realize is that Cython isn't designed to "protect" Python sources. It's a pretty weak protection, and is entirely accidental rather than by design.

The second thing is that any "protection" you do get is when the .c file is compiled to a .so/.pyd file. The .c file itself will be *very* easy to read and work out what your code does.

You can marginally improve things with the [Cython directive](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives) `emit_code_comments`. Turning that off well at least make sure that the original Cython code isn't copied into the C file. However all your Python strings will still be there as C strings.

Even if you compile the .c file then the strings will *still* be there in the compiled file in the data section of the .so/.pyd for anyone to see. It requires a little technical knowledge to find them, but not much.

In summary, Cython isn't really the tool for this. If you really care about hiding details of your implementation then you'll have to implement your own solution. But there's a few small steps to make it marginally better.

Comment: Thanks David, after reading various guides I came back to the "original" guide and found out that I am supposed to delete the .c file (really cant see how I missed that the first time(s))
If I create an array of chars something like this, will that be easy to find in .so file too?
dummy = [64,65,66,67.....]
dummy2 = ''.join(chr(i) for i in dummy)